# Select a button in excel based on its position (range)

Tags: excel, vba, button

I have been searching and there does not seem to be a clear answer.

In excel, using VBA, **is there a way to select a form button based on its position (e.g. over cell 'A3')?** It is possible to find the cell over which a button is located, but the opposite seems to be impossible (except, of course, by iterating over all buttons).

The reason why am asking is that I have a column where each cell has 2 possible values. If one of the values is chosen, I want to be able to delete a button in the same row but in a different column.

Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: Iterate over buttons and check their `TopLeftCell`.

Comment: Or name your buttons so that you know exactly which one needs to be deleted, ie: `button_1A`, `button_1B`, `button_2A` ...

Comment: @Bigben I mentioned iteration in the question. The reason that I am looking for a solution without iteration is because I have many buttons and excel could become sluggish

Comment: @Warcupine I thought about naming them but I could not find a way to do it practically for a column of ~200 buttons. If I rename one and drag its cell, it creates many buttons but they all have the same name

Comment: There is no solution without iteration AFAIK.

Comment: I guess you could iterate the naming. Then you only need to do it once?

Comment: In the past when I've needed tons of buttons or checkboxes I automate the creation. It's kind of a pain but less of a pain the other solutions.

Comment: Not sure I understand what is to be done... So, you have "a column where each cell has 2 possible values". Then you want deleting a button on the row where the cell (on that column) has been changed. Can you define a relation between the changed cell and the column where the button to be deleted stays? Is it possible to create such an algorithm? Are there many buttons on that specific row? If yes, will the button to be deleted, somehow chosen by some rule, according to one of the two possible values?

Comment: I am asking about such rules in order to create a piece of code to be run once, able to appropriately name the buttons to be deleted according to those  "column cells address/values" and the necessary buttons to be deleted... Then is should be easy, I think. Can you show us, at least, a picture with the buttons in discussion, explaining the rule to delete buttons according to the cell address and its value? We maybe will find such a rule...

Comment: @Jdrew: I am not sure, if I understand your "dragging" thing. Do you create the buttons or do the already exist in your document. And if you create them, would an iteration across the relevant rows be allowed? Then, you could give them a name that corresponds to their position.

Comment: @jdrew I have an answer for you, but before I write it up, can you tell me: 1) roughly how many buttons do you have on the sheet (100's, 1000's, 10,000's?) 2) are you using Form Control Buttons or ActiveX buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The premiss of the question seems to be that iterating over the Buttons on a sheets is somehow "Bad".  I'm guessing that "Bad" in this context means Slow.

The "obvious" method to locate a button over a given cell is to iterate the buttons on the sheet, and test the `TopLeftCell` property.  Testing this strategy shows that this *is* slow.  But it's not the iterating the buttons that's slow, it **accessing the `TopLeftCell` property that's slow**.

So, what else can we test while iterating?  Turns out, accessing the `.Top`, `.Left`, `.Height`, and `.Width` properties is quite fast.  These properties can be used to locate a button relative the  cells.

The OP doesn't specify if they are using ActiveX or Form Controls.  The following code is written for **Form Controls.** It can easily be adapted for ActiveX if required.

Assumptions:

1. Buttons are Form Controls.
2. There are only buttons on the sheet.  If other shapes exist then it might find one of those.
3. It's looking for a button whose top left corner is within the top left cell of the passed  range.
4. It is only called on non-hidden ranges.  If it is required to work for hidden ranges then it will require additional logic to avoid false positives.
5. If a button is not found it returns `Nothing`

```vb
Function GetButtonOverCell(rng As Range) As Object
    Dim btn As Object 
    Dim TL As Range

    Set TL = rng.Cells(1, 1)
    If TL.EntireRow.Hidden = True Or TL.EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then 
        Exit Function
    End If
    For Each btn In rng.Worksheet.Shapes
        If TL.Top <= btn.Top Then
            If TL.Left <= btn.Left Then
                If TL.Top + TL.Height >= btn.Top Then
                    If TL.Left + TL.Width >= btn.Left Then
                        If btn.TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False And btn.TopLeftCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
                            Set GetButtonOverCell = btn
                            Exit Function
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

On my hardware, testing this on a sheet containing 1600 buttons, this runs in about 0.1 seconds.  By contrast, using a method that test `.TopLeftCell` takes about 27s

Comment: I did not know about the time difference in accessing these properties. Thanks!

Comment: Nice idea... Voted it up.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend to use the following approach, as a lot of requirements have to be met, to make it work correctly. It is definitely not a good practise. But, as you do not want to iterate, this could be, what you are looking for.

**Idea**

Access the desired button via its position within the *ActiveSheet.Buttons()* collection and use the *row of the current cell* do determine it.

```
ActiveSheet.Buttons(ActiveCell.Row - [Number of initial rows without a button]).Visible = False
```

**Requirements**

1. All buttons were placed **in ascending order**, meaning the first button was placed in the first row that features a button, the second in the next row and so on.
2. You have **one button per row** (You can also adjust the code, if you have got the *same number of buttons per row*)
3. All buttons are located in **consecutive rows** (it would also work if you have the *same number of rows* between each *button row*. Of course, you would have to adjust the code)
4. You are fine with **hiding instead of deleting** a button (Obviously you cannot delete a button as it would impact the indexes of the *ActiveSheet.Buttons* collection)

**Screenshot**

The following screenshot was made, after `C3` was activated and the macro was run.

[image]

Comment: If you really want to use this solution, I would recommend to check the 'TopLeftCell' property **before** you hide a button and in case its row does not match the active cell's row, use @BigBen's **iteration** **as fallback process**. This way, it should not be so errorprone.